# Export to Excel display blank excel window

Tags: c#, php, export-to-excel

I have export to excel data feature in my projects using PHP and .Net C#. Two weeks ago, I noticed that the export to excel feature is not working in most of my projects. I tried to open after downloaded. I see a blank excel screen. Is anyone encountered the same problem? Please advise to resolve this.

Comment: What doesn't work? Where is the code? What library are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft has did some security update. Read here [Description of the security update for Excel 2013](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3115262)

To fix on a client system:

1) Open Excel -> Go to File Options

2) Click Trust Center -> Trust Center Settings

3) Go to Protected View. there are 3 options that show that were all clicked
Uncheck the first option that reads -- "Enable Protected View for files originating from the Internet"

Then open the file again.